# Implement a Non-Guessing Sudoku Solver

Tags: code-golf, game, puzzle-solver, sudoku

Implement the shortest Sudoku solver.

**Sudoku Puzzle:**

```
 | 1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9
-+-----------------------
A|   3   |     1 |
B|     6 |       |   5
C| 5     |       | 9 8 3
-+-----------------------
D|   8   |     6 | 3   2
E|       |   5   |
F| 9   3 | 8     |   6
-+-----------------------
G| 7 1 4 |       |     9
H|   2   |       | 8
I|       | 4     |   3
```

**Answer:**

```
 | 1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9
-+-----------------------
A| 8 3 2 | 5 9 1 | 6 7 4
B| 4 9 6 | 3 8 7 | 2 5 1
C| 5 7 1 | 2 6 4 | 9 8 3
-+-----------------------
D| 1 8 5 | 7 4 6 | 3 9 2
E| 2 6 7 | 9 5 3 | 4 1 8
F| 9 4 3 | 8 1 2 | 7 6 5
-+-----------------------
G| 7 1 4 | 6 3 8 | 5 2 9
H| 3 2 9 | 1 7 5 | 8 4 6
I| 6 5 8 | 4 2 9 | 1 3 7
```

**Rules:**

1. Assume all sudokus are solvable by logic only.
2. All input will be 81 characters long. Missing characters will be 0.
3. Output the solution as a single string.
4. The "grid" may be stored internally however you wish.
5. The solution must use a non-guessing solution. (see [Sudoku Solver](http://www.sudokusolver.co.uk/))

**Example I/O:**

```
>sudoku.py "030001000006000050500000983080006302000050000903800060714000009020000800000400030"
832591674496387251571264983185746392267953418943812765714638529329175846658429137
```

Comment: You should really add a time limit.

Comment: Pretty sure this has been done before. There are some very short solvers out there, but some puzzles will take a long long time to solve using a naive algorithm

Comment: @JPvdMerwe: Good point, but a time limit would be hard to standardize.

Comment: @gnibbler: It might have been done before (but not on codegolf.se). I think it will still be fun to solve as well as add some value to the community, especially if one goes about it honestly.

Comment: I like this one. I've been hesitant to try an actual golf solution, and I've been thinking about writing a Sudoku solver (it seems like a fun exercise). I think it's something people like me, who've never golfed before, could use as a jumping-off point. And once I come up with one, I might then golf it.

Comment: @Andy: gnibbler and JPvdMerwe brought up a good point that naive solvers could eventually solve this questions given enough time. My intention for this question was for it be solved specifically by logic. Since no one has answered I think I will add that specification.

Comment: @snmcdonald: Pardon my ignorance, but what exactly do you mean by "by logic"? Do you mean, no brute-forcing?

Comment: @Andy: see http://www.sudokusolver.co.uk/step.html

Comment: is bruteforce guessing?

Comment: @stole: yes it is. We could have another Code Golf that is a guessing only solution. As JPvdMerwe suggested it might be a good idea to add a time limit to a guessing solution.

Comment: You could make use of answers here: http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=96

Comment: This is definitely an interesting problem. Unfortunately, since it's a lot harder than brute-forcing it, and brute-forcing it appears to be quite fast ( http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/378/implement-a-brute-force-sudoku-solver ), I'm not sure that there's much point in solving it logically other than the challenge. If all you care about is solving it, then brute force does just fine (and it's a lot easier to write). Nonetheless, solving it logically is definitely a great challenge.

Comment: @Jonathan, IMO the main point to solving it logically is to estimate the difficulty.

Comment: Problems "solvable by logic only" is very vague. Do you mean, perhaps, using only the basic steps of a) Writing a value in a cell for which it's value not in its row, column, and block b) Identifying a number that can only go in one place in its row, column, or block, and writing it there?

Answer (score 6):

**RUBY** (<strike>449</strike> 436 chars)

```
I=*(0..8)
b=$*[0].split('').map{|v|v<'1'?I.map{|d|d+1}:[v.to_i]};f=b.map{|c|!c[1]}
[[z=I.map{|v|v%3+v/3*9},z.map{|v|v*3}],[x=I.map{|v|v*9},I],[I,x]
].map{|s,t|t.map{|i|d=[a=0]*10;s.map{|j|c=b[i+j];c.map{|v|d[v]+=1if !f[i+j]}
v,r=*c;s.map{|k|b[i+k].delete(v)if j!=k}if !r 
s[(a+=1)..8].map{|k|s.map{|l|b[i+l]-=c if l!=k&&l!=j}if c.size==2&&c==b[i+k]}}
v=d.index 1;f[i+k=s.find{|j|b[i+j].index v}]=b[i+k]=[v]if v}}while f.index(!1)
p b*''
```

Example:

```
C:\golf>soduku2.rb 030001000006000050500000983080006302000050000903800060714000009020000800000400030
"832591674496387251571264983185746392267953418943812765714638529329175846658429137"
```

quick explanation:
Board `b` is an array of 81 arrays holding all the possible values for each cell.
The array on line three holds [offset,start_index] for each group (boxes,rows,columns).
Three tasks are performed while iterating through the groups.

1. The value of any cell of size 1 is removed from the rest of the group.
2. If any pair of cells contain the same 2 values, these values are removed from the rest of the group.
3. The count of each value is stored in `d` - if there is only 1 instance of a value, we set the containing cell to that value, and mark the cell fixed in `f`

Repeat until all cells are fixed.

Comment: You can omit the brackets in `I=*(0..8)`, will save 2 chars.

Comment: I get `sudokusolver.rb:8: unterminated string meets end of file` if I start it with `ruby1.8  sudokusolver.rb 030...`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like there is an extra ' on the last line.  Not sure how that got there...

Answer (score 3):

## Prolog - 493 Characters

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).
a(X):-all_distinct(X).
b([],[],[]).
b([A,B,C|X],[D,E,F|Y],[G,H,I|Z]):-a([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I]),b(X,Y,Z).
c([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I|X])-->[[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I]],c(X).
c([])-->[].
l(X,Y):-length(X,Y).
m(X,Y):-maplist(X,Y).
n(L,M):-l(M,L).
o(48,_).
o(I,O):-O is I-48.
:-l(L,81),see(user),m(get,L),seen,maplist(o,L,M),phrase(c(M),R),l(R,9),m(n(9),R),append(R,V),V ins 1..9,m(a,R),transpose(R,X),m(a,X),R=[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I],b(A,B,C),b(D,E,F),b(G,H,I),flatten(R,O),m(write,O).
```

**Output:**

Inputting:
`000000000000003085001020000000507000004000100090000000500000073002010000000040009`
Outputs:
`987654321246173985351928746128537694634892157795461832519286473472319568863745219`

Inputting:
`030001000006000050500000983080006302000050000903800060714000009020000800000400030`
Outputs:
`832591674496387251571264983185746392267953418943812765714638529329175846658429137`

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>491</s> <s>490</s> <s>488</s> <s>465</s> 463 bytes

```powershell
$w=,0*81;$c=,(1..9)*81
$a=(24,24,6)*3|%{,(0..8|%{($r++)});,(0..8|%{$v%81;$v+=9});$v++;,((1,1,7)*3|%{+$q;$q+=$_});$q-=$_}
filter g($v,$i){if($v){$a|?{$i-in$_}|%{$_|%{$c[$_]=$c[$_]-ne$v}};$w[$i]=$v;$c[$i]=@()}}
$args|% t*y|%{g($_-48)($i++)}
for(;$a|%{($b=$_)|?{($v=$c[$_])}|?{(($c[$b]|%{"$_"})-eq$v).Count-eq$v.Count
$c[$b]|%{$_}|group|? C* -eq 1|? N* -in $v|%{$v=+$_.Name;1}}|%{$b|?{"$v"-ne$c[$_]}|%{$c[$_]=@($c[$_]|?{$_-notin$v})}
g($v[0]*!$v[1])$_
1}}){}
-join$w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHbjpswEH3nK1zkNDhA5PulCO1K@74/sIpQNku2tClsSEJaEb49HUM2VZ3IPnPmjOeM@WjOZXv4Xu52V7zN@ys@5wldWJbhTZ5EbLl0BKIAr/OIywT@mizEZdYnEV0uLYAIt3FMBpLdGdzNfH0X5w5oOGPIRSxhiZlqY7zP8D7OceHz@9SDYFvtjmWL3iPcJbgifbUFRHq8vjz0uEqrGkT@8sJvmxdcrPLpSOsSd8OQ4fMLroDsMs8DeozIMIDz9v1wmaHj4g9UwvVFKi2JcOVdB9umjTLo4ed4BR8EukHf29Vk8GHkg9cVaEJchANJyz04Wz41p/o44gkGd5l3@t42p4/LA3paINAgBvAZYFUj3I1vlMe4WD6vf5UZG8bBXqFXiLvQzzN2H/5N@hhNwL9FkdbNEZ6jG8C/f64Xulp8gYOtCC4CuI30Q5D@aEBzvg5B8BgFQRKhkApKKaN@ab8p@PnlrKDWk4LyifckFSNHDZOTakraMfCUoGESIIRCK7hyTBspnRbWcMWUYVxLuJdZZaQWjnNtnBKSWSeFZdxokEDCKu4Ed8woK7WGDbAwISKj4zn9b4FL5Qfgt1hRczfDRoef/LgMjMtv895Ubj46njsLBqTgjEvNjHBWCcUct@CVcQiMdmBOWsdhFDAOtB/SS7Q0QhoumFPaWi2MVJy5uXdM0AXNUO87IHw4vTU/TwnC5e@PcnMs31CO4OuMubY8nHZHIL7i7adyzIQ4uiXTTVMf11V9uNeTb5@FYTBc/wI)

Implemented Solving methods: Single, Naked Pair, Naked Trio, Naked Quad and Hidden Single.

See [Terms related to solving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Sudoku#Terms_related_to_solving)

See also the [code with debug output](https://tio.run/##ZVVbb@o4EH7Pr/BJ3Y2dm3Ijl0VRu1rt2@po3xFCAUybXZrQJEAp@Ld3x3YgKcegxB7PfHP77OzqI2vaV7bdfuG/mqZu/lh1ZV3907ANa1i1YihHetvVO13TNvtKbqJN3bwVnbNr6iUjs7Lq5ri01bupjxSdNQQDH8AWH2e4nKv1qqjW5broBCZeDfLNWye8nD3bifjZt31@DsRUR84GkcFs5rluOEfOv3VZIcOgNriwvylErpuOFBT8J4BLERGeZiQ0ZZSu28@QhQI6p5rULjcE4nYAEf0YgKnKSAwdAHU0Gg@orbcHtpYanG1bBhg/riADhvtnva865Gw7lI3w8GeOP52G7bbFihnIsA3HuHP2gESli2W5LbsTqqvtafB1H9gDE01U@xof9ezYlB1ziqZRFlDK9PJ4xqccL24QIvkTcqB4oR2PYhSD2AQiM/2QmiGV5TSsIVB@mwFwIIChsGPoPlXVh6vzj3sNMQx0MUyCP25x/KIxph8imYlPFv6gSLj8psvpnfu7cDnEcBOp@rzWbYf6oLhiBC7GariurvRdzEUOC355aer97vKE@gazd@RfHtHP4o0NZqvdYPUkrR7PuljpV/u2bjrYcIWd@zerXrpXLh1IiUV0U7dgIZ1QKFA/dSrmUz6ik/SzUx2ykaF96@7nXVfHWf9SHmU6UjGc0QBk0MCb/PyFj7ltGGbqa3iV28R33YzKVZGTILLhHwNrIBn72nqCG8uinE5vEnx4TP0pPlh5BmJ4W7BH4DKwE2Vr4fcpfreAMmL/3RGTgd4vcGxtXNKzPMD0DF2DMpfAIVVrvBAPWf9cvaBw@MD5VN1QOT5M1Z2UPxPKOcTevLTQxs48gSXAL5wopQSXIm4NKEimkhkELyESCt7Abw9NuVgS3Mn1UvBExwudU@AGBNc3TszVVLupfaOT2XPpCf005WnAB1mo3OpJMfW5zG0J7nR80EVKMgA@JPtMRqxzqrqDihw4pCAqNvPmJlxVM39OgfSA1tPjdllAiyWT8PELmv1MNM0mSPdCz/N8T4xYPCbwEyNLQy8VwtALlFwIvVDKvMSPlJbaTOVCiEJPt4VbPQ2DSebHSRRlcZgmwcSfJH4QR4Drp5MkisMsCOIkm4SRn2ZRmPpBEoMKbKSTIAuDzE8maRTH8IB5mOgIrnWKLujx@k1q9@v6vz18OdjHjq06thbHRZ133LB2vxWfot/w5qopd3RM@k1nVVddUVbtzZ7@fjXUNf71Pw).

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 295 bytes

```perl
sub P{$r=$p/9;$c=$p%9;$q=3*~~($r/3)+$c/3}sub N{($i,$u)=@_;P;$G[$p]=$u*$i;$R[$r]{$i}=$C[$c]{$i}=$Q[$q]{$i}=$u}sub S{if($p>80){print@G;exit}if($G[$p]){S(++$p);$p--}else{N($_,1),S(++$p),$p--,N($_)for grep{P;$R[$r]{$_}+$C[$c]{$_}+$Q[$q]{$_}<1}1..9}}@G=split'',$ARGV[0];N($G[$p=$_],1)for 0..80;$p=0;S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5Ra4MwEMe/Sh9u1FSr57JuSpbh2INvxVXYi4gwsSMgWxoVBiH96s6o6x3kLr//cfeXjWoP49gNn5tMg@Igg5hBPdW7qV443V2vDqiAEhfqgBo7eNQOCA8GwpOKZQzSAmTJYdiBYHAqQJUahOHwVkC9tu8FXNZ2mHfkWpwdkC8REi2V@O6TlDW/ojcWzwuJzh3XBUkYyP3eNG3X6KMDlRcSb1U8q3gWkvOP2nypRursZqEy7r8F264WKvMcmtD3Y2OSlHeyFf1268HrKf0osGTH5TqHqpwO2a3o@xFOHjiyfBxHpIgYoo1H@xymtBFHFCMLKd4v3EKkM8On8GGZWsRo/lhE8Q8)

Shortened from 339 to 317 to 315 to 314 to 310 to 309 to 298 to 295

Comment: nice. there is [the test case in the Prolog answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28137/80745) `000000000000003085001020000000507000004000100090000000500000073002010000000040009`. Would you like to run your solution with this test case?

Comment: Nice example :-) . It is kind of worst case, with a solution having 987654321 in the first line. It runs into the time limit on TIO, but run locally on my PC it still outputs the correct solution -- after around 10 minutes. There is, of course, room for performance optimization, but it would make the code longer.

Comment: Thanks. This is CodeGolf, so a performance does not matter

Comment: I'm afraid the `grep` uses guesswork and your solution uses a brute force.  I'm guessing :) your answer would be better suited for [Implement a Brute Force Sudoku Solver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/378/implement-a-brute-force-sudoku-solver). See rule 5 in this question.

Comment: I have seen the discussion to the question and I am not quite sure what "brute force" means. I use a simple backtracking algorithm. So this is based on trying numbers in a free call, going on and roll back if there is a dead end. First I thought of a real brute force approach, trying each number in each free cell and then checking if this is a solution. Although it may take longer than the age of the universe, it will eventually find the solution. Btw. there are cases where it is unavoidable to try several candidates for a solution unless you blow up the logic in an unreasonable way.

Comment: If backtracking were not allowed, a solution in Prolog should not be valid either because Prolog does backtracking inherently. It is just hidden under the surface.

Comment: `Prolog does backtracking inherently`. Yes, it is. I mean, it's worth looking at Perl answers were on [Implement a Brute Force Sudoku Solver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/378/implement-a-brute-force-sudoku-solver)