# Implement Bogosort

Tags: code-golf, random, sorting

Is [solving Sudoku](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/355/implement-a-non-guessing-sudoku-solver) too hard? Even the [brute force](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/378/implement-a-brute-force-sudoku-solver) version? Here's a coding exercise that's a little easier. I hope. :-P

Write the shortest function to implement bogosort. In specific, your function should:

- Take an array (or your language's equivalent) as input
- Check if its elements are in sorted order; if so, return the array
- If not, shuffle the elements, and start again

The shortest entry wins. In the case of a tie, a function that supports a custom comparator (and/or pseudorandom number generator) is favoured. Any remaining ties are resolved by favouring the earlier submission.

---

**Clarifications:** You can use any element type you want, as long as there's some way to order them, of course. Also, the shuffling has to be uniform; none of this "I'll just quicksort it and call it shuffled" business. :-)

Comment: What are the element types? int or strings?

Comment: @Alexandru: Either is fine. You choose.

Comment: Adding a custom comparator will increase the code length so a winning entry will not have a custom comparator. I think breaking the tie doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Alexandru: If you have to code your comparison by hand (e.g., in GolfScript), making it support custom comparators is easy. However, your point is generally valid.

Comment: sorted ascending, descending or either?

Comment: It's possible that this algorithm can fail when using pseudo random generator. eg when the length of the list exceeds say 2000, there are 2000! states for the list which may exceed the number of interal states of the prng.

Comment: @Eelvex: Either is fine. Indeed, with a custom comparator, changing a `<` to `>` is all that's required to change the sort direction. :-)

Comment: @gnibbler: Bogosort is not required to terminate. In fact, its worse case complexity is O(∞), according to Wikipedia.

Comment: Yes, the relevant quote from wikipedia "However, if a pseudorandom number generator is used in place of a random source, it may never terminate, since these exhibit long-term cyclic behavior."

Comment: Must we check of the array is sorted prior to shuffling?  Or can we initially shuffle then check whether it's sorted?

Comment: @Nemo157: That is fine too.

Comment: Just so it's been said, requiring a function that *returns* something does actually block some answers that might otherwise be interesting/valid approaches.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### APL(Dyalog), 20

```
{⍵≡⍵[⍋⍵]:⍵⋄∇⍵[?⍨⍴⍵]}
```

**Explanation**

`⍵` is the (right) argument
`⍵≡⍵[⍋⍵]`: Checks if `⍵` sorted equals `⍵` itself
`:⍵`: If yes, then return `⍵`
`∇⍵[?⍨⍴⍵]`: Else, generate an array of 1 to `⍴⍵` (length of `⍵`) in random order, reorder `⍵` according to that (`⍵[...]`), and apply the function to it (`∇`)

---

Suddenly revisiting this problem and...

### APL(Dyalog), 19

```
{∧/2≤/⍵:⍵⋄∇⍵[?⍨⍴⍵]}
```

Was just thinking about sorting an array in the check makes it kind of pointless (not saying that Bogosort is meaningful), a more accurate implementation would be `∧/2≤/⍵`, and that happens to lower the char count.

Answer (score 17):

### Perl 6: 23 chars

```
@s.=pick(*)until[<=] @s
```

Comment: Is this a function in perl? It looks nice :)

Comment: If you don't know, `[<=]` checks if a list is sorted: `[<=] (1, 2, 3,) == (1 <= 2 <= 3) == (1 <= 2) and (2 <= 3)`, and `.pick(n)` chooses n random elements from a list, and `.pick(*)` lets Perl pick all elements. http://use.perl.org/~masak/journal/40459

Comment: This must be Perl 6.  I've never seen `pick` used before, let alone `[<=]`.  Where in the documentation are those?

Comment: @GigaWatt This is Perl 6 (not Perl 5). `[]` is reduce operator which takes operator between square brackets. For example, `[<=] 1, 2, 3` is `1 <= 2 <= 3` (and yes, you do ranges like this in Perl 6). In this case, it's used to determine if elements are in order. `.pick(*)` method shuffles the list (`pick(N)` picks `N` elements from list). `.=` calls method, and assigns the result to the variable. As for documentation - well, for now only Perl 6 specification exists - http://feather.perl6.nl/syn/, but it exists.

Answer (score 7):

### Ruby - 33 characters

```
g=->l{l.shuffle!!=l.sort ?redo:l}
```

Comment: 1 char less: `g=proc{|l|0until l.sort==l.shuffle!}`

Comment: @AShelly, your version doesn't work. My version (5 chars less) `f=->l{l.sort!=l.shuffle!?redo:l}` (Ruby 1.9)

Comment: can someone please explain to me why `redo` works with a `proc` but not in a classical method with `def...end`? I thought `redo` only works with loops?

Comment: Ok never mind, i found something in 'The Ruby Programming Language' book: ”`redo` […] transfers control back to the beginning of the proc or lambda“. It simply is that way.

Answer (score 7):

#### APL (22)

```
{(⍳X←⍴⍵)≡⍋⍵:⍵⋄∇⍵[X?X]}
```

Usage:

```
    {(⍳X←⍴⍵)≡⍋⍵:⍵⋄∇⍵[X?X]} 3 2 1
1 2 3
```

Explanation:

- `⍋⍵`: returns the *indexes* of the items in sorted order, so `⍋30 10 20` gives `2 1 3`
- `(⍳X←⍴⍵)≡⍋⍵:⍵` Store the length of input list in X. If range `[1..X]` is equal to the sorted index order, the list is sorted, so return it.
- `⋄∇⍵[X?X]`: if this is not the case, recurse with shuffled array.

Answer (score 6):

#### *Mathematica*, <s>40</s> 37

```
NestWhile[RandomSample,#,Sort@#!=#&]&
```

With whitespace:

```
NestWhile[RandomSample, #, Sort@# != # &] &
```

Comment: If you ignore errors, you can save three bytes with `#//.l_/;Sort@l!=l:>RandomSample@l&`

Comment: 13sh bytes in Mthmca.

Answer (score 5):

### J - <strike>34</strike> 27

```
f=:({~?~@#)^:(1-(-:/:~))^:_
```

eg:

```
f 5 4 1 3 2
1 2 3 4 5

f 'hello'
ehllo
```

The **{~ ?~@#** part shuffles the input:

```
({~ ?~@#) 1 9 8 4
4 8 9 1
({~ ?~@#) 'abcd'
bdca
```

Answer (score 4):

### Python 61

Sorts in place.

```
import random
def f(l):
 while l!=sorted(l):random.shuffle(l)
```

Comment: Your function does not return the array on success.

Comment: Sorts in place. The passed array is modified.

Comment: The question does say that the function is supposed to return the array though - even if it isn't technically necessary to get the result.

Comment: `from random import*` can save a char.

Comment: This may not always work: (from python random module documentation): "Note that for even rather small len(x), the total number of permutations of x is larger than the period of most random number generators; this implies that most permutations of a long sequence can never be generated."

Comment: Wouldn't a lambda be shorter?

Comment: @J843136028, Python doesn't let you have a while loop in a lambda

Answer (score 3):

## K, <strike>31</strike> 25

<strike>`{while[~x~x@<x;x:x@(-#x)?#x];x}`</strike>

```
{x@(-#x)?#x}/[{~x~x@<x};]
```

.

```
k){x@(-#x)?#x}/[{~x~x@<x};] 3 9 5 6 7 9 1
`s#1 3 5 6 7 9 9
```

.

```
k){x@(-#x)?#x}/[{~x~x@<x};] "ascsasd"
`s#"aacdsss"
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 94

```
from itertools import*
def f(a):return [x for x in permutations(a) if x==tuple(sorted(a))][0]
```

Other python answers use random.shuffle(). The documentation of the python random module states:

> Note that for even rather small len(x), the total number of
>   permutations of x is larger than the period of most random number
>   generators; this implies that most permutations of a long sequence can
>   never be generated.

Comment: Do a lambda instead; I think it would be shorter. Also note that you can do `return[x...` as opposed to `return [x...`. Same with `permutations(a) if` -- it could be `permutations(a)if`.

Comment: `lambda a: [x for x in __import__("itertools").permutations(a) if x==tuple(sorted(a))][0]` is 88 bytes

Answer (score 2):

### Python - 61 chars

Recursive

```
from random import*;f=lambda l:l==sorted(l)or shuffle(l)>f(l)
```

Comment: Your function returns True or False, not the array.

Comment: Also note that recursive solutions are doomed to failure even for small inputs.

Comment: @hallvabo: I actually want to write a tail-recursive solution in Scheme, which won't deplete your stack, of course.

Comment: @hallvabo, Alexandru had already done the obvious Python solution, so I was just going for something different here. Of course the recursive solution is just for fun and not a serious contender

Comment: `from random import*` might be shorter.

Comment: @J843136028, thanks. But I seem to have gotten the original byte count wrong, so it's still 61

Answer (score 2):

### Python (69 chars)

```
from random import*
def f(a):
 while a>sorted(a):shuffle(a)
 return a
```

Sorts integers in increasing numeric order.
Note that recursive solutions, like

`from random import*;f=lambda a:a>sorted(a)and(shuffle(a)or f(a))or a`

will fail due to stack overflow for even small inputs (say N>5), because Python does not do tail-call optimisation.

Answer (score 2):

## D without custom comparator: 59 Characters

```
R f(R)(R r){while(!isSorted(r))r.randomShuffle();return r;}
```

More Legibly:

```
R f(R)(R r)
{
    while(!r.isSorted)
        r.randomShuffle();

    return r;
}
```

## D with custom comparator: 69 Characters

```
R f(alias p,R)(R r){while(!isSorted!p(r))r.randomShuffle();return r;}
```

More Legibly:

```
R f(alias p, R)(R r)
{
    while(!isSorted!p(r))
        r.randomShuffle();

    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Scala 73:

```
def s(l:Seq[Int]):Seq[Int]=if(l==l.sorted)l else s(util.Random.shuffle l)
```

In Scala, we can check whether the compiler did a tail-call optimization:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def s(l:Seq[Int]):Seq[Int]=if(l==l.sorted)l else s(util.Random shuffle l)
```

and yes, it did. However, for a short List of 100 values:

```
val rList = (1 to 100).map(x=>r.nextInt (500))
s(rList)
```

took nearly 4 months to complete. ;)

Answer (score 2):

**C# (184 chars)**

```
T[]S<T>(T[]i)where T:IComparable<T>{T l=default(T);while(!i.All(e=>{var r=e.CompareTo(l)>=0;l=e;return r;})){i=i.OrderBy(a=>Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();l=default(T);}return i.ToArray();}
```

It's not really nice to do this in C#. You have to support generics to support both value and reference types. There is no array shuffle function or function to check if something is sorted.

Does anybody got any tips to make this better?

Edit
Version that only sorts int (134 chars):

```
int[]S(int[]i){var l=0;while(!i.All(e=>{var r=e>=l;l=e;return r;})){i=i.OrderBy(a=>Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();l=0;}return i.ToArray();}
```

Answer (score 2):

## GNU/BASH 65

```
b(){ IFS=$'\n';echo "$*"|sort -C&&echo "$*"||b $(shuf -e "$@");}
```

Comment: Hmm, can I get a special exception to the *return the array* rule since bash functions can only literally return an unsigned byte?

Answer (score 2):

### C++11, 150 characters

```
#include<deque>
#include<algorithm>
void B(std::deque &A){while(!std::is_sorted(A.begin(),A.end())std::random_shuffle(myvector.begin(),myvector.end());}
```

Just.. made for fun.

Comment: std::random_shuffle is not uniform. In the clarifications it is stated: "Also, the shuffling has to be uniform"

Comment: Okay... i didn't know it was not uniform.

Comment: It relies on rand() which is not uniform -- see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3924.pdf . Not many other people are seem to be following so meh i guess it's not a big deal.

Comment: So if I use a fully random one like using srand(time(0)) then does it count?

Comment: Problem is that rand is not guaranteed to have good quality of random numbers let alone uniformity, some produce non-random low-order bits. I guess it doesn't nor should matter in the end. I only got 8 more bytes using a uniform distributor with std::shuffle and so forth, good enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

## C++14, 158 bytes

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
[](int*a,int s){std::random_device r;for(std::knuth_b g(r());!std::is_sorted(a,a+s);std::shuffle(a,a+s,g));return a;};
```

Comment: you can reduce `<algorithm>` to `<regex>`; the latter includes the former automatically, also, you can remove whitespaces in the two `#include`s

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>85</s> <s>82</s> <s>56</s> <s>55</s> 52 bytes

<sup>-26 bytes thanks to mazzy's suggestions</sup>
<sup>-1 byte thanks to AdmBorkBork</sup>
<sup>-3 bytes thanks to mazzy</sup>

```powershell
for($l=$args;"$l"-ne($l|sort)){$l=$l|sort{random}}$l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JclNCoAgEEDhvaeIGCphWtjPKjyMkNZiyhiDFubZrWj5vnf4y3JYLVEGp2N2nhsgDYaXMJVAZbvbF@7g@ZQyfuuPyGaf/ZYSUBZJiApc0SjssMcBRynq@qfxpQEV9jI/)

PowerShell does have a relatively cheap array comparison by casting them to strings and comparing that.

Comment: Move your `param` initialization into your `for` initialization to save a byte -- `for($l=$args;`

Comment: nice. `-ne` casts the right operator to a scalar type of the left operator. so, you can save a few bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JclNCoAgEEDhvaeIGCphWtjPKjyMkNZiyhiDFubZrWj5vnf4y3JYLVEGp2N2nhsgDYaXMJVAZbvbF@7g@ZQyfuuPyGaf/ZYSUBZJiApc0SjssMcBRynq@qfxpQEV9jI/ "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>98</s> 92 chars

More precisely ECMAScript 2015 (ES6)

**Minified:**

```js
let b=r=>{for(;!r.every((o,t)=>o==[...r].sort()[t]);)r.sort(()=>Math.random()-.5);return r};
```

**Invocation:** `console.log(b([3, 2, 1, 5, 67, 4, 6, 5, 6, 4]))`

**Not minified:**

```
let bogoSort = (myArray) => {
  while (!myArray.every((v, i) => v == [...myArray].sort()[i])) {      
    myArray.sort(() => Math.random() -0.5)    
  }
  return myArray
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `myArray.every()` is an element-wise compare function. Comparing shuffled with sorted array
- `someArray.sort()` sorts in place so saving assignments, but also needs cloning for the sorted array
- `[...myArray]` clones the array ([array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment))
- `() => (Math.random() > .5) ? 1 : -1` is a custom compare function. Coin flip whether to order an element in front or behind

Answer (score 2):

## [Go 1.20+](https://go.dev), 95 bytes

```go
import(."math/rand";."sort")
func f[T Interface](I T){for!IsSorted(I){Shuffle(I.Len(),I.Swap)}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZDPSsQwEMbvfYoxpwRixX8g6j7AgAeheytFYjfZ7domJUkRCX0SL0XwIXwTfRuTdhHRS2bm4_t9meT1bWumj17UT2IroRONzpquN9bnRHWevA9eHV99PSwazUkn_O7ECr0hNzlxUSMsU4OuQZVrQO2lVaKWFUVYs6CMPUJXRJfcUGSh2A1KtZJific1ZRzz4ln0bBwP13z6l15Co72DsoplSY5ZSWIwQ6mHYKUfrIY2KsjGfz7naMNhn2YGj8a0PwSWTXWL5b76C6VNfkEhGXkyrtLB0zhmC5N-KS4SMizgejXz4YJf8nN-xk9jLsWCZfc26q2e-8P7pmmp3w)

Expects input to implement [`sort.Interface`](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#Interface), which wants:

- `Len() int`: gets the number of elements.
- `Less(i, j int) bool`: checks whether the element at index `i` is less than the element at index `j`.
- `Swap(i, j int)`: swaps elements at indexes `i` and `j`.

Why is this `1.20+`? See below.

#### [Go](https://go.dev), 158 bytes, seeded ints (pre-1.20)

```go
import(."math/rand";."sort";."time")
func f(I[]int)[]int{Seed(Now().Unix())
for!IntsAreSorted(I){Shuffle(len(I),func(i,j int){I[i],I[j]=I[j],I[i]})}
return I}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LU_BisIwFLz3K7I5vUCsuO6CIB485iJC8VR6CJpotHmVmKJQ-iWClAU_wk_xbzZpvbxh5r0Z5t3_9lX3OsvtSe4VsdJgYuy5cj6l2nr6rL0ezd6PQYOUWukPYydxR-cpvQQtojdWUZboGrdEg8gLg571s8mU2sGqugJLN2huwMJZ5b4E-svSqSwEhL1gTXaotS4VlAoD5TEKDD-SmNSI3BRc5MdiEQePtGVt4pSvHRLRflr2rv4HYKRJ1i6YSwQNQ5Uf_sun_JtP2lDi4-m6Af8B)

#### [Go](https://go.dev), 131 bytes, unseeded ints (pre-1.20), truly random (post-1.20)

```go
import(."math/rand";."sort")
func f(I[]int)[]int{for!IntsAreSorted(I){Shuffle(len(I),func(i,j int){I[i],I[j]=I[j],I[i]})}
return I}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY4_CoMwGMX3nCLNlEBq6T8olA4dsxUcxSFoYmNNlJhM4tRjdJFCD9Gj9DY16vI-3uP9-N7rXdTDt-HZgxcCaq4MULqprYuQ1A59vJPr0-85ZzhCmrv7xnKTo3OE2jFDBEhvMigxS1JlHJm0k7VdMePaqxXx2BI5ZqSL717KSuBKmNHSwGFFSxiwjiUqpSwp00sQGmxPemCF89ZA1i9TJmoaignswM2OcGWwxPPfAz3SPd3RbU8IWJhhmO8f)

This solution is marked as both "unseeded" and "truly random" due to a change in Go v1.20 that changed the global, [default random number generator to be seeded "randomly"](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.20#:%7E:text=The%20math/rand%20package%20now%20automatically%20seeds%20the%20global%20random%20number%20generator) rather than be default, deterministic `rand.Seed(1)` in pre-1.20 versions.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript 291 characters

min

```
function f(e){var t=[].concat(e).sort();t.e=function(e){var n=true;t.forEach(function(t,r){if(t!=e[r])n=false});return n};while(!t.e(e.sort(function(){return Math.floor(Math.random()*2)?1:-1}))){console.log(e)}return e}
```

un-min

```
function f(a) {
var b = [].concat(a).sort();
b.e = function (z) {
    var l = true;
    b.forEach(function (v, i) {
        if (v != z[i]) l = false;
    });
    return l
};
while (!b.e(a.sort(function () {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) ? 1 : -1;
}))) {
    console.log(a);
}
return a;
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling I've said this before, but you can remove all the `var`s. Just make them all implicit globals, it's just about making the code as short as possible.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 71 characters

```
from random import*
def b(l):
 while l!=sorted(l):shuffle(l)
 return(l)
```

Not the shortest one, but it works.

Ungolfed:

```
from random import *
def bogosort(list):
    while list != sorted(list):
        shuffle(list)

    return(list)
```

**Usage:**

Input: `b([1, 7, 3, 9, 2])`

Output: `[1, 2, 3, 7, 9]`

Comment: Return isn't a function, you don't need parenthesis...

Comment: you can use `l<sorted(l)` instead of `!=`

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab, 59 bytes

Relatively straight forward approach:

```
x=input('');while~issorted(x);x=x(randperm(numel(x)));end;x
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 22 bytes

```
$:@({~?~@#)`]@.(-:/:~)
```

This is a recursive, tacit monad using an agenda. Here's how it works:

Let `y` be our list. First, the verb on the right of the agenda is `-:/:~`. This a verb graciously provided by [Leaky Nun](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30115841#30115841). It matches (`-:`) whether or not the input is sorted (`/:~`) using a monadic hook. (`(f g) y = y f (g y)`) This returns a one or a zero accordingly. The left hand side of the agenda is a gerund of two verbs: on the right is the identity verb `]`, and on the left is where the recursion takes place. The agenda selects either the identity verb at position `1` if the list *is* sorted, and the longer verb at position `0` if the list *isn't* sorted.

`$:@({~?~@#)` calls `$:` (the longest verb it is contained in) atop the result of `{~?~@#` on `y`. This shuffles the list, as `?~@#` takes the permutations of the length of `y`, being randomly-sorted indices of `y`. `{~`, in a monadic hook, returns a list from `y` whose indices are the right arg. This shuffled list is then called again with the agenda, and repeats until it is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 8 bytes

```
[oSog?_i
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@x@dH5yfbh@f@f//f1MdBRMwMtdRMAQA)**

Alternatively, run [this version](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@x@dHxyfn26f@f//f1MdBRMwMtdRMAQA) to see it print each shuffle as it goes along! The code works like this:

```
[          \ Infinitely:
 oS        \   Shuffle the stack
   og?     \   If it's sorted (ascendingly):
      _i   \     Print and terminate
```

If you want to sort descendingly, just replace `og` with `oG`.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
[Ð{Q#.r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@x99eEJ1oLJe0f//0YY6ZjrmOkZgbKljEvs1L183OTE5IxUA)

Explanation:

```
[        # Infinite Loop start
 Ð       # Push input
  {Q#    # If input is sorted, break loop
     .r  # Otherwise, shuffle
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes, language postdates challenge

```
ẊŒ¿’$¿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ASUA2v//4bqKxZLCv@KAmSTCv////1s1LDEsMCw0LDdd9W5vLWNhY2hl)

### Explanation

```
ẊŒ¿’$¿
     ¿  While
 Œ¿’$     the input is not in its earliest possible permutation (i.e. sorted)
Ẋ       shuffle it
```

`Œ¿` assigns a number to each permutation of a list; 1 is sorted, 2 has the last two elements exchanged, etc., up to the factorial of the list length (which is the list in reverse order). So for a sorted list, this has the value 1, and we can decrement it using `’` in order to produce a "not sorted" test that's usable as a Boolean in a while loop condition. The `$` is to cause the condition to parse as a group.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (v2), 5 bytes

```
≤₁|ṣ↰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1HnkkdNjTUPdy5@1Lbh//9oEx1DHWMdSx2L2P9RAA)

Function submission. (The TIO link uses a command-line argument that automatically wraps a function into a full program.)

### Explanation

```
≤₁|ṣ↰
≤₁      Assert that {the input} is (nonstrictly) sorted in ascending order
  |     Output it
  |     Exception handler: if an assertion fails:
   ṣ      Randomly shuffle {the input}
    ↰     and run this function recursively on it, {outputting its output}
```

Prolog (the language that Brachylog compiles into) is tail-recursive, so this function ends up being compiled into a tight loop.

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 166 bytes

Meh.

```cpp
#import<algorithm>
#import<random>
#define r b.begin(),b.end()
template<class v>
v f(v b){auto a=std::mt19937();while(!std::is_sorted(r))std::shuffle(r,a);return b;}
```

This should work on all STL containers that have `begin()` and `end()`.

Ungolfed:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
template <class v>
v f(v b) {
    auto a = std::mt19937();
    while (!std::is_sorted(b.begin(),b.end()))
        std::shuffle(b.begin(),b.end(),a);

    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 15 bytes

```apl
(?⍨∘≢⊇⊢)⍣{⍺≡∧⍺}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X8P@Ue@KRx0zHnUuetTV/qhrkeaj3sXVj3p3Pepc@KhjOZBR@z/tUduER719j/qmevo/6mo@tN74UdtEIC84yBlIhnh4Bv8HaswFqgIZZsaVppALAA)

Comment: 14 bytes [`?⍨∘≢⍛⊇⍨⍣{⍺≡∧⍺}`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/3/5R74pHHTMedS561Dv7UVc7iNu7uPpR765HnQsfdSwHMmr/pz1qm/Cot@9R31RP/0ddzYfWGz9qmwjkBQc5A8kQD8/g/4@6FuUCVYGMM@NKU8gFAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
∈&ṣ≤₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/qG3Do6bG8v@POjrUHu5c/KhzCZD7/3@0kY6xjoGOqY5hLAA)

When I first saw ais523's Brachylog answer (as opposed to his Jelly answer, because if I'm not mistaken user62131 was also him), I wondered, what if it used backtracking instead of recursion? So at first, I tried `ṣ≤₁`. Turns out, since choosing something at random doesn't produce multiple outputs so much as it just produces one output nondeterministically, the shuffle predicate `ṣ` can't be backtracked to, so running that will simply fail unless you're lucky enough to shuffle it right on the first try. After that, I tried `pṣ≤₁`, which worked most of the time, but since a finitely long list has finitely many permutations, it still failed at random sometimes. After having abandoned the goal of achieving length reduction, I finally came up with this:

```
         The input
∈        is an element of
         an unused implicit variable,
 &       and the input
  ṣ      shuffled randomly
   ≤₁    which is increasing
         is the output.
```

[(Demonstration of randomness)](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1FHh9rDnYurH@7qVKt91LnkUVPj///RRjrGOgY6pjqGsQA)

Although it actually can be a bit shorter if we take some liberties with I/O...

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 4 bytes

```
⊆ṣ≤₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/qG3Do6bG8v@Putoe7lz8qHMJkPf/f7SRjrGOmY6pjmEsAA)

In order for the output to be useful, the input must not contain any duplicate elements, because in addition to sorting the input, this bogosort predicate adds in a random number of duplicate elements and zeroes. (Hypothetically, it could add in anything, but it just kind of doesn't.) Ordinarily I wouldn't bother mentioning something so far from correctly functioning, but I feel it's in the spirit of the challenge.

```
⊆        An ordered superset of the input
 ṣ       shuffled randomly
  ≤₁     which is increasing
         is the output.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>11</s> 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
_eZñ}a@öx
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=X2Va8X1hQPZ4&input=WzksNywzLDQsMl0)

```
_eZñ}a@öx     :Implicit input of array U
_             :Function taking an array as argument via parameter Z
 e            :  Test Z for equality with
  Zñ          :  Z sorted
    }         :End function
     a        :Repeat and return the first result that returns true
      @       :Run this function each time and pass the result to the first function
       öx     :  Random permutation of U
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 28 bytes

```perl6
{({.pick(*)}...~.sort).tail}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WqNaryAzOVtDS7NWT0@vTq84v6hEU68kMTOn9n9xYqVCmkK0oY6xjlGs9X8A)

Anonymous code block that shuffles the list until it is sorted. Note that it sorts the list at least once, which is allowed. And no, the `{.pick(*)}` can't be replaced with `*.pick(*)`

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

```
Wn=Q.SQSQ;Q
```

Pretty happy with this, probably can be golfed a bit more

## Explanation

```
Wn=Q.SQSQ;Q
W    While
  =Q.SQ    Variable Q (input variable) shuffled 
 n  Does not equal
       SQ    Variable Q sorted
             ;  Do nothing (loop ends)
              Q    And output variable Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzzPNlAvODA40Drw//9oCx0zHZNYAA)

Comment: You can shorten `=Q.SQ` to `=.SQ` for -1 byte (works with other operators too, like `=QhQ`-> `=hQ`)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 252

Requires java 10 as the `var`keyword is used.

```
import java.util.*;interface B{static int c(List<String>a,int i){return i>0?Math.max(a.get(i-1).compareTo(a.get(i)),c(a,i-1)):-1;}
static void main(String[]p){var a=Arrays.asList(p);while(c(a,a.size()-1)>0)Collections.shuffle(a);System.out.print(a);}}
```

### Explained

```
import java.util.*;                              // you don't get a lot for free in java
interface B{
  static int c(List<String>a,int i){             // recursive comparator method, i is index to compare a[i-1] with a[i]
    return i>0?                                  // still not at the first element?
           Math.max(                             // return the max of...
             a.get(i-1).compareTo(a.get(i)),     // - string comparison of a[i-1] and a[i]
             c(a,i-1))                           // - recursive call c for i-1
           :-1;                                  // i=0 -> return -1
  }
  static void main(String[]p){                   // entry point
    var a=Arrays.asList(p);                      // convert the input array in a List (so we can use Collections functions)
    while(c(a,a.size()-1)>0)                     // as long as c()>0, at least one element is not in correct order
      Collections.shuffle(a);                    // shuffle the list
    System.out.print(a);                         // print the ordered list
  }
}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##NY@xUsMwDIZ3nsKjzTW@diWQHrDCVDaOQecqiYIT5ywlpeTy7MY5YP2k//ulDmYouvNnStSPIYrqMrCTkLe3JQ2CsQaH6mlhASGnMlJOvxDL/UkiDU0Fu42RWSLKFAdF1f74CtLaHr402AZFU3Ew1oV@hIhv4R8as3M6p/PQ3BWHcr3565gDnVUPNOjfiveP0SwzRAUPjzHClS3wdoEeTXlpyaPePGCZvlGbrKv25jl4j04oDGy5neo6b4EpT1cW7G2YxI5ZLRtb15TSBXz@NTUTS5KIyIk84w8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
{ÞṠ¬|Þ℅:
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJ7w57huaDCrHzDnuKEhToiLCIiLCJbNCwgMiwgMywgMV0iXQ==)

##### Explanation

```python
{ÞṠ¬|Þ℅:  # Implicit input
{   |     # While loop
 ÞṠ       # (Condition): Is sorted?
   ¬      #              Logical NOT
     Þ℅   # (Body): Randomly shuffle
       :  #         Duplicate
          # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

### C (203 chars, no input loop: only the func)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define P (int*a,int n){
#define F for(i=0;i<n;i++){
int i,j,v;s P F if(a[i]>a[i+1])return 0;}return 1;}void h P F v=a[i];a[i]=a[j=rand()%n];a[j]=v;}}void b P while(!s(a,n-1))h(a,n);}
```

This is the same as the following, where we also read the array from stdin and write out the sorted array. Since the Q asked for the function and not a whole program...

### C (296 chars)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define P (int*a,int n){
#define F for(i=0;i<n;i++){
int i,j,n,v,x[999];s P F if(a[i]>a[i+1])return 0;}return 1;}void h P F j=rand()%n;v=a[i];a[i]=a[j];a[j]=v;}}void b P while(!s(a,n-1))h(a,n);}main(){while(scanf("%d",&v)==1)x[n++]=v;if(!s(x,n))b(x,n);F printf("%d\n",x[i]);}}
```

Compiling may give warning (implicit declarations). Hardencoded array size limit of 999 elements. Fragile.

if there's no need to pre-check if the array is sorted, it can be done in 284.

### C (251 chars, was 284)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define F for(i=0;i<n;i++){
int i,j,n,v,a[999];s(int n){F if(a[i]>a[i+1])return 0;}return 1;}void h(){F v=a[i];a[i]=a[j=rand()%n];a[j]=v;}}void b(){while(!s(n-1))h();}main(){while(scanf("%d",&a[n++])>0);b();F printf("%d\n",a[i]);}}
```

(using globals instead of function args).

Answer (score 0):

### R, 82 characters

Since I wrote it for [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12824/sorting-a-list-of-strings-without-using-any-built-in-sort-method) I thought I'll add it there as well. Slightly modified here to accomodate question criteria.

```
b=function(a){while(any(apply(embed(a,2),1,function(x)x[1]<x[2]))){a=sample(a)};a}
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (using Array.sort()): 91

Utilising Array.sort():

```
function s(a){while((a=a.sort(function(){return 2-Math.random()*4|0}))!=a.sort());return a}
```

### JavaScript (avoiding Array.sort()): 186

Not using the built-in .sort() method (randomising method stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript#answer-6274398)):

```
function s(a){while(function(b,c,d){for(;c<b.length-1;){d&=b[c]<=b[++c]}return!d}(function(t,n,i){i=a.length;while(i--){n=Math.random()*i|0,t=a[i],a[i]=a[n],a[n]=t}}()||a,0,1));return a}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java - 207 bytes

```java
boolean sorted(Integer[] n,int i){while(i-->1)if(n[i]<n[i-1])return false;return true;}void bogo(Integer[] n){List<Integer>l=Arrays.asList(n);while(!sorted(n,n.length)){Collections.shuffle(l);l.toArray(n);}}
```

**Ungolfed** [try online](http://ideone.com/WvCKi4)

```java
boolean sorted(Integer[] n,int i)
{
    while(i --> 1) // i..1
        if(n[i] < n[i-1]) // ascending order
            return false;

    return true;
}

void bogo(Integer[] n)
{
    List<Integer>l = Arrays.asList(n);

    while(!sorted(n, n.length))
    {
        Collections.shuffle(l); // shuffle
        l.toArray(n); // re-fill the array
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 147 bytes

```
import java.util.*;void A(List<Long>b){for(;;){for(int B=1;B++<b.toArray().length;){if(b.get(B-1)>b.get(B))break;return;}Collections.shuffle(b);}}
```

This sorts in ascending order, To make it sort in descending order, simply replace `b.get(B-1)>b.get(B)` with `b.get(B-1)<b.get(B)`.

Ungolfed:

```
import java.util.*;

void A(List<Long> b) {
    for (;;) {
        for (int B = 1; B++ < b.toArray().length;) {
            if (b.get(B - 1) > b.get(B))
                break;
            return;
        }
        Collections.shuffle(b);
    }
}
```

Making this function compilable costs 9 bytes, resulting in a 156-byte program:

```
import java.util.*;class a{void A(List<Long>b){for(;;){for(int B=1;B++<b.toArray().length;){if(b.get(B-1)>b.get(B))break;return;}Collections.shuffle(b);}}}
```

---

## Java (lambda expression), 111 bytes

```
(b,B)->{for(;;){for(B=1;B++<b.toArray().length;){if(b.get(B-1)>b.get(B))break;return;}Collections.shuffle(b);}}
```

This is a `java.util.function.BiConsumer<java.util.List<Long>, Integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

## C, 111 bytes

This answer takes bogus sort one step further: It doesn't shuffle the entire array before rechecking, it just makes a singe random swap before rechecking. For extra measure, that single random swap always swaps with the first entry, so the general random swap actually takes two iterations. Inefficient, yes, but hey, it's bogus sort, and it saves one call to `rand()`!

```
#include<stdlib.h>
t,r;b(int*d,int s){r=rand()%s;t=*d;*d=d[r];d[r]=t;for(r=s-1;r--;)d[r]>d[r+1]&&(b(d,s),r=0);}
```

Note that since the mixing loop is implemented via recursion, this will crash for larger input arrays (= more than eight elements on my machine) due to stack exhaustion.

Ungolfed:

```
void b(int*data,int size){
    //First, swap random element with the first element.
    int randomIndex = rand()%size;
    int temp = *data;
    *data = data[randomIndex];
    data[randomIndex] = temp;

    //Check if array is sorted
    for(int i = size-1;i--;) {
        if(data[i]>data[i+1]) {
            //array is not sorted, start over
            b(data,size);
            i = 0;  //don't resume loop on return
        }
    }
}
```

Test with

```
int main(){
    int data[] = {8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    int size = sizeof(data)/sizeof(*data);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) printf("%d ", data[i]);
    printf("\n");

    b(data, size);

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) printf("%d ", data[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, <s>104</s> 81 bytes

```
DEF B A@D
SWAP A[0],A[RND(LEN(A))]FOR I=0TO LEN(A)-2IF A[I]<A[I+1]GOTO@D
NEXT
END
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
œ.ΔD{Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6GS9c1NcqgP//4820zHVMdIx1jHUMYkFAA)

**Explanation**

```
œ       Create list with all permutations
 .Δ     Return the first element that satisfies the followng:
   D{Q  Check if element is sorted.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
WnSQKO.pQ;K
```

*Previous Solution*

```
L?n.SbSbybb
y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzwvONDbX68g0Nr7//9oQx0FYx0FUx0FEx0Fo9h/@QUlmfl5xf91UwA)

```
WnSQKO.pQ;K
      .pQ    Generate a list of all permutations of input
    KO.pQ    K = random permutation in the list
WnSQK    ;   While(sorted(input) != K): do nothing
          K  print K
```

*Previous Solution:*
Compiled to python:

```
assign('Q',eval_input())
@memoized
def subsets(b):
 return (subsets(b) if ne(shuffle(b),Psorted(b)) else b)
imp_print(subsets(Q))
```

Basically:
*Shuffle the list, if it isn't equal to the sorted list:*
recursively call.
*Else:*
Return it

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
ΩS=O§!←P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zKYFv/Q8sVH7VNCPj//3@0oY6xjpGOSSwA)

Husk does not have random numbers, so this uses the array itself to get a permutation. I genuinely don't know whether this would complete.

### Explanation

```
ΩS=O§!←P
Ω        Until
 S=O     the argument is ordered
       P take it's permutations
      ←  take its first element
    §!   return that permutation
```

Comment: Given that it looks like the `§!←P` part just returns the list as is (as the permutations returned always has the original list as the first element), this will only finish if the list is inputted sorted

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 14 bytes

```
{{__$=!}{mr}w}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fmKljpZlb9L@6Oj5exVaxtjq3qLa89n9dwn9DAwA)