# Morse sudo-ku-de

Tags: code-golf, array, conversion, sudoku, morse

<sup>Hehe, see what I did with the title? Anyways...</sup>

Your job is to create a sudoku solver that accepts input in Morse code and creates output in Morse code. Here's the Morse code numbers for reference:

```
0:  -----
1:  .----
2:  ..---
3:  ...--
4:  ....-
5:  .....
6:  -....
7:  --...
8:  ---..
9:  ----.
```

## Rules:

- The code must define a function `s(x)` which returns the answer.
- The function must accept a string or character array (whichever is the "string of characters" type of your relevant language) with 81 Morse code numbers (see above) separated by spaces. Each 9 Morse code numbers is one row of the sudoku puzzle. Known numbers should be represented by their appropriate Morse code number, while unknown numbers should be `0` in Morse code.
- The function must perform calculations and then return a string of Morse code numbers similar to the input but as a solved board (separated by spaces).
- Be mindful of the [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

Here's an example. I have the following input string:

```
----- -.... ----- ...-- ----- ----- ---.. ----- ....- ..... ...-- --... ----- ----. ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ....- ----- ----- ----- -.... ...-- ----- --... ----- ----. ----- ----- ..... .---- ..--- ...-- ---.. ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- --... .---- ...-- -.... ..--- ----- ----- ....- ----- ...-- ----- -.... ....- ----- ----- ----- .---- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -.... ----- ..... ..--- ...-- .---- ----- ..--- ----- ----- ----. ----- ---.. -----
```

...which in regular numbers, is this:

```
0 6 0 3 0 0 8 0 4 5 3 7 0 9 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 6 3 0 7 0 9 0 0 5 1 2 3 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 1 3 6 2 0 0 4 0 3 0 6 4 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 6 0 5 2 3 1 0 2 0 0 9 0 8 0
```

And when I put the Morse code string through a correct function, it should then look like this (a solved sudoku board):

```
..--- -.... .---- ...-- --... ..... ---.. ----. ....- ..... ...-- --... ---.. ----. ....- .---- -.... ..--- ----. ....- ---.. ..--- .---- -.... ...-- ..... --... -.... ----. ....- --... ..... .---- ..--- ...-- ---.. ---.. ..--- ..... ----. ....- ...-- -.... --... .---- --... .---- ...-- -.... ..--- ---.. ----. ....- ..... ...-- ..... -.... ....- ---.. ..--- --... .---- ----. ....- ---.. ----. .---- -.... --... ..... ..--- ...-- .---- --... ..--- ..... ...-- ----. ....- ---.. -....
```

...which is this in regular numbers:

```
2 6 1 3 7 5 8 9 4 5 3 7 8 9 4 1 6 2 9 4 8 2 1 6 3 5 7 6 9 4 7 5 1 2 3 8 8 2 5 9 4 3 6 7 1 7 1 3 6 2 8 9 4 5 3 5 6 4 8 2 7 1 9 4 8 9 1 6 7 5 2 3 1 7 2 5 3 9 4 8 6
```

Any language allowed. Have fun, and golf away!

Comment: So...this is a sudoku solver and a number converter?

Comment: @J42161217 In all essence, yes.

Comment: In this case this is a dupe you know..

Comment: I'm not going to hammer this because of some weirdness about guessing/non-guessing but this is pretty much a dupe of one of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/355/31625) or [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/378/31625). In the future I'd recommend using [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/31625) to work on your posts before posting. Good luck!

Comment: May we use an array of strings (each being a Morse digit) for I/O, instead of one long space-separated string?

Comment: Will the input only ever have one solution? If not, what do we do if there are multiple solutions?

Comment: @Adám Must be one long string.

Comment: May the output have extra spaces (e.g. two spaces between numbers or leading/trailing spaces)?

Comment: [Relevant Meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9384/43319)

Comment: (I don't actually understand the title)

Comment: @JoKing, I think it's supposed to be a play on "pseudo-code".

Comment: @JoKing Or an almost-valid bash command? ... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ (I think `sudo -ku de command` would mean "run 'command' as user 'de', ignoring the cached credentials")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 42 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
⌂morse{1↓∊' ',¨⍺⍺∊⍕¨⊃⌂sudoku⍎¨9 9⍴⍺⍺⍵⊆⍨≠⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1FPU25@UXFqteGjtsmPOrrUFdR1Dq141LsLhDq6HvVOBfK6moHKiktT8rNLH/X2HVphqWD5qHcLVFHv1kddbY96VzzqXABk1/5Pe9Q2AajqUd9UT3@gzkPrjR@1TQTygoOcgWSIh2fw/zQFdV0QUNDVAwIFCBvIAolAxGEksqwehNSDq0ToBRF66HrRSIgJWGRRzNQlaDLUDVA2isv1CLkBN4lsph6Sq/D5AsXNMF9g9aMeMW5AjQu47RBb9FDcgM0EPcxYUwcA)

`⌂morse{`…`}` derive a function where `⍺⍺` is shorthand for the to/from-Morse function

`⍵` the argument string

`≠` Boolean mask where not a space

`⍵⊆⍨` cut where false (this gives us a list of Morse digit strings)

`⍺⍺` convert Morse digits strings to string of digits

`9 9⍴` **r**eshape to 9 rows and 9 columns

`⍎¨` evaluate each character (turns them into integers)

`⌂sudoku` find all solutions

`⊃` pick the first solution

`⍕¨` stringify each integer

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten)

`⍺⍺` convert string of digits to list of Morse digit strings

`' ',¨` prepend a space to each Morse digit string

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten)

`1↓` drop the first character (the leading space)

Comment: APL has a method to find sudoku solutions? My grandma will like this c: Does it have one for crosswords also?